# Deploy Scrapy Project with Streamlit

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, streamlit

I have a scrapy spider that scrapes products information from amazon based on the product link.

I want to deploy this project with streamlit and take the product link as web input, and product information as output data on the web.

I don't know alot about deployment, so anyone can help me with that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a public repository on GitHub with streamlit and connect your account with 0auth. Then you can deploy it on the streamlit servers after signing in the streamlit website.

Comment: Ok, But how do i run the spider from the streamlit code. I know how to create a streamlit web app, I don't know how to connect my web scraper with streamlit app.

Comment: You need to take it in a loop and push it into a public repo then the run is done by streamlit.

Answer (score 0):

You can run scrapy from a script using [scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) module

basically, you can run the spider and export the data temporarily and use it in your streamli app -

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "items.json": {"format": "json"},
    },
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Now you can save this script and run using `subprocess` which will export the data into `items.json`. Use it in your app.

Here is a helpful [streamlit cloud scrapy thread](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/run-scrapy/12044/11) with [public streamlit-scrapy project github repo](https://github.com/estkae/StreamlitEmail_app)